# How to display div of related content from template when clicked in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a question on how best to achieve a feature in Angular. I have tried a number of solutions from `ng-click`, `ng-if`, `ng-show` and combinations of those but no luck in my novice state.

Currently I `ng-repeat` through an array of json data as `li`.

What I want to achieve is when I click one of the looped `li` it opens and displays the 'info div' with the related info to the li clicked (preferably by use of template). If user clicks another li it simply switches out the data to display correctly again.

Any advice on how to proceed to this feature would be greatly appreciated. I have provided my existing code as well as a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Auzy/pen/LGvrNw).

JS:

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller('starWarsCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.data = [
    {"name": "Obi-Wan Kenobi",
     "index":88,
      "cat": "Jedi"},
    {"name": "Yoda",
     "index":69,
      "cat":"Jedi"},
    {"name": "Lando",
     "index":31},
    {"name": "Han Solo",
     "index":90},
    {"name": "Darth Vader",
     "index":98},
    {"name": "Jar-Jar Binks",
     "index":80},
    {"name": "Mace Windu",
     "index":45},
    {"name": "Chewy",
     "index":76}
  ];
})
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="starWarsCtrl">
  <input type="text" id="query" ng-model="query"/>
<div class="bscroll">
  <ul>
      <li class="box" ng-repeat="i in data | filter:query | orderBy: orderList">
        <h2>{{i.name}}</h2>
        <p>{{i.index}}{{i.cat}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
  <div class="info">The details would appear here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution is to add an `ng-click` to your `<li>` that calls a function to select the item:

```
<li class="box" ng-repeat="i in data | filter:query | orderBy: orderList" ng-click="select(i)">
    <h2>{{i.name}}</h2>
    <p>{{i.index}}{{i.cat}}</p>
</li>
```

and then your js:

```
$scope.select = function (item) {
    $scope.selectedItem = item;
}
```

and your info div:

```
<div class="info" ng-if="selectedItem">
    Name: <span ng-bind="selectedItem.name"></span><br>
    Index: <span ng-bind="selectedItem.index"></span>
    <div ng-if="selectedItem.cat">
        Category: <span ng-bind="selectedItem.cat"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This should at least be enough to get you started in the right direction.

Updated pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WrqXJa